# How can I hide TabBar Swift UI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a `TabBarView` in the root view. In one of the parent views that's nested within the root view, I'd like the tab bar to hide when navigating from that parent view to the child view. Is there any func or command to handle that?

Something like this:

`ContentView (with TabBarView) - > ExploreView (Called in TabBarView ) -> MessagesView (Child of ExploreVIew - Hide Tab bar)`

My code can be seen below.

```
TabView{

    NavigationView{
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ExploreView()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                }, label: {
                    HStack{
                        Image("cityOption")
                        Text("BER")
                        Image("arrowCities")
                    }.foregroundColor(Color("blackAndWhite"))
                        .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .semibold))
                }),trailing:
                    HStack{
                        Image("closttop")
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                            .padding(.trailing, 125)

                        NavigationLink(destination: MessagesView()
                            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Messages"), displayMode: .inline)
                            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Image("writemessage"))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("blackAndWhite"))
                        ){
                            Image("messages")
                        }
                    }.foregroundColor(Color("blackAndWhite"))
            )
        }
    }
    .tabItem{
        HStack{
            Image("clostNav").renderingMode(.template)
            Text("Explore")
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
        }.foregroundColor(Color("blackAndWhite"))
    }
    SearchView().tabItem{
        Image("search").renderingMode(.template)
        Text("Search")
    }
    PostView().tabItem{
        HStack{
            Image("post").renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable().frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        }
    }
    OrdersView().tabItem{
        Image("orders").renderingMode(.template)
        Text("Orders")
    }
    ProfileView().tabItem{
        Image("profile").renderingMode(.template)
        Text("Profile")
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to show view over tabbar,  You should use 'self.viewController?.present(style: .fullScreen)' to present view.

Comment: @ChamanSharma thanks for your answer! I'm new to Swift UI, and do not clearly understand where should i call this?  I don't have a viewController...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Create CustumPresentViewController.swift -

```
    import UIKit
    import SwiftUI

    struct ViewControllerHolder {
         weak var value: UIViewController?
    }

    struct ViewControllerKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: ViewControllerHolder { return 
        ViewControllerHolder(value: 
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController ) }
    }

    extension EnvironmentValues {
        var viewController: ViewControllerHolder {
            get { return self[ViewControllerKey.self] }
            set { self[ViewControllerKey.self] = newValue }
      }
    }

    extension UIViewController {
         func present<Content: View>(style: UIModalPresentationStyle = 
         .automatic, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
             // Must instantiate HostingController with some sort of view...
             let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: 
              AnyView(EmptyView()))
             toPresent.modalPresentationStyle = style
             // ... but then we can reset rootView to include the environment
             toPresent.rootView = AnyView(
             builder()
            .environment(\.viewController, ViewControllerHolder(value: 
             toPresent))
    )
    self.present(toPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

#### Use this in required View -

```
@Environment(\.viewController) private var viewControllerHolder:  
ViewControllerHolder

private var viewController: UIViewController? {
    self.viewControllerHolder.value
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Text("Navigate")
        }.onTapGesture {
             self.viewController?.present(style: .fullScreen) {
                                    EditUserView()
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it worked perfectly! Do you actually know how to make views to change like Navigation Link does? Because now it is presented from the bottom up.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late here, on iOS 16 you could use **ContentView().toolbar(
.hidden, for: .tabBar)**

So in your case, it would be like as below,

```
struct ExploreView: View {
    var body: some View {
        some_view {

        }
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you animate it though?

Answer (score 0):

in a normal iphone environment the tabbar vanishes from itself if you are navigating....or are u running in another environment?

check this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var hideTabbar = false
    @State var navigate = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            TabView {

                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("without tab")){
                      Text("aha")
                    }
                        .tabItem {
                            Text("b")
                    }
                }.tag(0)
                Text("Second View")
                    .tabItem {
                        GeometryReader { geometry in

                            Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                            //        Text("Second")
                            Text("\(geometry.size.height) - \(geometry.size.width)")

                        }
                }.tag(1)
            }
        }
    }//.isHidden(self.hideTabbar)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do use standard IOS environment. As it's seen in my code, I have `TabBarView` which calls for `ExploreView` and other Views. But when I tap on a child of `ExploreView` (NavigationLink inside of  `ExploreView` file) , the `ExploreView` changes itself to `Child View` which NavigationLink leads to , without hiding `Tab bar` on the bottom..